# Add a constant date column in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a table in mysql.

```
+------+---------+
|value |  unit   |
+------+---------+
|    2 | DAY     | 
|    3 | MONTH   | 
+------+---------+
```

this is just a part of my table. it consists of many rows

i want to add a date column to this table with a constant date. say '2009-01-01'
type of the column should be date.

```
+------------+------+---------+
| date       |value |  unit   |
+------------+------+---------+
| 2009-01-01 |    2 | DAY     | 
| 2009-01-01 |    3 | MONTH   | 
+------------+------+---------+
```

i want to create table_2

```
create table table_2 as
select value,unit,`dates` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2009-01-01' from table;
```

but getting syntax error.

any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Storing multiple types of things in the same column makes that table hard to work with and slow. Consider having separate day, month, and date columns. Perhaps you should explain why you've designed your table like this?

Comment: Why store a constant at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_2(
dates DATE
) SELECT  '2009-01-01' AS dates, value, 
unit FROM table_1
```

for more information Visit here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: Hi i have update it with simple and easy sql. Try it, it should work.